# How to POST long URL using AFNetworking

Tags: php, ios, afnetworking

I am hitting very long URL to the server like below URL which contains 1000 of numbers , I am getting an error :HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.  when i hit in browser . If i hit with some less number Server is replying with required results.

How can i hit the long URL using AFnetworking and handling php code , Please suggest me answer .

http://bb.trackfleet.biz/smscalling/json_array.php?contacts=+9198739443xxx:9900456xxx:+919953107xxx:9611443xxx:+919986447xxx:9986781xxx:+919901434xxx:+919686647xxx:+919036256xxx:+918197711xxx:9449800xxx:+918884420xx:

Answer (score 0):

User getPath function of afhttpclient

```
    NSDictionary *params1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             appdelegate.uuid, @"param",
                             nil];
    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:
                            base_url];
    [client getPath:@"url" parameters:params1 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
```

Comment: I used this but parameter is not getting attached to URL , How can i see whole parameter appended with dictionary ?

Comment: if you want it on php side then just use print_r($_GET)